# How can I create a Sass mixin with a class as a variable

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I am trying to write something like this :

```
@mixin variableChild($child:".theChild") {
    //some css
    $child {
     //css specific to the child
    }

}

#parent { @include variableChild(".specificChild"); };
```

So it would generate this CSS :

```
#parent {//some css}
#parent .specificChild {
   //css specific to the child

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You were almost right, you just missed the `#{}` around your child selector I think. There’s more information about it in the [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).

```
@mixin variableChild($child:".theChild") { 
    #{$child} {
        color: red;
    }
}

#parent {
    @include variableChild(".specificChild");
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UrLdB/